# Integration of the tail of a Gaussian function with Scipy, giving zero instead of 8.19e-26

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am trying to integrate a Gaussian function, the limits are way inside the Gaussian tail, so trying the integrate.quad gave me zero. Is there a way to integrate a Gaussian function that suppose to give extremely small answer?

The function's integrand is:

```
sigma = 9.5e-5
integrand = lambda delta: (1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))*np.exp(-(delta**2)/(2*sigma**2))
```

I need to integrate between `10^-3` to `0.3`

[image]

With Wolfram Alpha I got an answer of 8.19e-26
But with Romberg integration of Scipy I got zero. Can I turn the knobs in Scipy to integrate such a small result?

Comment: try `romberg` with arguments `tol=1e-28, rtol=1e-28`; you will get `3.25e-25` which is in line with mathematica result

Comment: Can you show the details of how you got 8.19e-26 from Wolfram Alpha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `F(x; s)` be the CDF of the normal (i.e. Gaussian) distribution with
standard deviation `s`.  You are computing
`F(x1;s) - F(x0;s)`, where `x0 = 1e-3` and `x1 = 0.3`.

This can be rewritten as `S(x0;s) - S(x1;s)` where `S(x;s) = 1 - F(x;s)` is the
"survival function".

You can compute this with the `sf` method of the the `norm` object of `scipy.stats`.

```
In [99]: x0 = 1e-3

In [100]: x1 = 0.3

In [101]: s = 9.5e-5

In [102]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [103]: norm.sf(x0, scale=s)
Out[103]: 3.2671026385171459e-26

In [104]: norm.sf(x1, scale=s)
Out[104]: 0.0
```

Note that `norm.sf(x1, scale=s)` gives 0.  The exact value of this expression is a
number that is smaller than can be represented as a 64 bit floating point value (as @Zhenya points out in a comment).

So this calculation gives the answer 3.267e-26.

You could also compute this with [`scipy.special.ndtr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtr.html).  `ndtr` computes the CDF of the standard normal distribution, and by symmetry, `S(x; s) = ndtr(-x/s)`.

```
In [105]: from scipy.special import ndtr

In [106]: ndtr(-x0/s)
Out[106]: 3.2671026385171459e-26
```

---

If you want achieve the same result using numerical integration, you'll have to experiment with the error control parameters of the integration algorithm.  For example, to get this answer using `scipy.integrate.romberg`, I tweaked `divmax` and `tol`, as follows:

```
In [60]: from scipy.integrate import romberg

In [61]: def integrand(x, s):
   ....:     return np.exp(-0.5*(x/s)**2)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*s)
   ....: 

In [62]: romberg(integrand, 0.001, 0.3, args=(9.5e-5,), divmax=20, tol=1e-30)
Out[62]: 3.2671026554875259e-26
```

With `scipy.integrate.quad`, it required the trick of telling it that 0.002 was a "special" point that would require more work:

```
In [81]: from scipy.integrate import quad

In [82]: p, err = quad(integrand, 0.001, 0.3, args=(9.5e-5,), epsabs=1e-32, points=[0.002])

In [83]: p
Out[83]: 3.267102638517144e-26

In [84]: err
Out[84]: 4.769436484142494e-37
```

Comment: as I said as a comment to @Zhenya answer, this is far off from Wolfram Alpha result. Try evaluating `SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[0, 9.5*10^(-5)], .003]` or `CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 9.5*10^(-5)], -.003]` in Wolfram Alpha. The result is `O(e-219)`.

Comment: But the lower limit is 0.001, not 0.003.

Comment: Sure, my bad. this settles it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
>>> from scipy.special import erfc
>>> erfc(1e-3/9.5e-5/np.sqrt(2.))
6.534205277034387e-26
```

That far in the tail you're better off using a complemented error function (erfc) or, possibly, [erfcx](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfcx.html), which is the complemented error function scaled by `exp(x**2)`.

Comment: you’re testing the ‘easy’ extreme of integration, i.e. the `delta=1e-3`. If you now run the test for `delta=.3` your test will fail, i.e. `erfc(.3/9.5e-5/np.sqrt(2.))`. I don't downvote you, as mistakes simply happen.

Comment: In the comment above it was `erfc(.3/9.5e-5/np.sqrt(2.))==0`, I missed the `==0` bit

Comment: @flebool Given that `erfcx(0.3/9.5e-5 / np.sqrt(2.))` is roughly `2e-4`, you're talking about an additive correction of the order of `1e-2165457`

Comment: And that's impressively small, I agree. But even the other extreme is impressively small, way in the range of numerical noise. Wolfram Alpha 's result is of the order of `10^(-219)`, see [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1s3ajv6oq0)

Comment: What I mean here is that the result `erfc(1e-3/9.5e-5/np.sqrt(2.))=6.534205277034387e-26` above is wrong, as shown by Wolfram Alpha's calculation.

Comment: @Zhenya, your expression is missing a factor of 2, so you get an answer that is twice the value in my answer.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, mine's quick-and-dirty and can be a factor of two off. If you care to mention `erfc/erfcx` (why are there are two implementations, faddeeva/cephes?) in your answer, I'll happily delete mine.

Comment: @flebool: There is a mistake in the Wolfram Alpha calculation that you linked; the value in the numerator of the argument should be `0.001`, not `0.003`.

Comment: My bad. This settles it, sorry

Comment: @Zhenya: No need to delete your answer.  I'm not sure bringing in erfc would make what I wrote clearer or more helpful.  (Why two implementations?  Mists of time and all that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help,

after more consultations I went to the numerical integration option, after checking with c++ script I've found up that if I set divmax = 120 at the scipy.integrate.romberg I arrive to the same result that I got at Wolfram Alpha.

But this solution takes lots of time to calculate. I will try to work with the error function to see if I can make sense of it..

Cheers

Comment: This is a standard, well-defined, widely-used quantity.  You shouldn't use a numerical integration to compute it, especially since the numerical integration is giving the wrong answer.  @flebool gave a Mathematica formula for this value: `SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[0, 9.5*10^(-5)], .001]`.  Try it out in Wolfram Alpha.  If you still don't believe it, try computing the numerical integration by adding the results of numerically integrating over two subintervals, from 0.001 to 0.002, and from 0.002 to 0.3.

Comment: So I tried the norm.sf solution and it indeed gives the same answer and much faster.